# Proving Nonexistence of an Identity in a given Groupoid

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Take $G = \{\alpha | \alpha : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\}$ and for
$\alpha, \beta \in G$, define the mapping $\alpha \cdot \beta =
\alpha \circ \beta - \beta \circ \alpha$. I want to prove that $G$ has no
identity element in this case.

Assume for the sake of contradict there exists $e \in G$ that is an identity
element. This implies that $\forall a \in G$, $a \cdot e = e \cdot a = a.$
This implies that 
$$\color{red}{a \circ e - e \circ a = e \circ a - a \circ e = a}$$

One thing that worries me is that this suggests that
$e \circ e - e \circ e = e$, which may imply (although I am not sure) that
$e$ maps everything to $0$. Is there a way I can prove that the
$0$ function (i.e. the function that maps everything to $0$) cannot be an
identity function?

Comment: Your red equation proves that $a=-a$ for all $a\in G$, regardless of what $e$ is.

Comment: well, yeah. $a= 0 \circ a - a\circ 0= -a(0)$ a constant.  Not all functions are constants.  and $a = a\circ 0 - 0 \circ 0 = a(0$ so the constant is 0.  If the zero function is the identity *every* function is the zero function.

Comment: Actually my comment abuses notation.  More to the point $a(x) = [e\circ a - a \circ e](x) = e(a(x)) = a(d(x) ) = 0 - a(x) = -a(x)$ so$a(x) = -a(x)$ so $a(x) = 0 \forall x \in \mathbb R$.  Thus $G = \{e:\mathbb R \rightarrow \{0\}\}$ which just isn't what $G$ was defined to be.